# How to solve my wifi issues in Ubuntu 16.04 with rtl8821ae?

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, realtek, realtek-wireless

I'm a new Ubuntu user. I've installed it a month ago, but there's an issue that I've not been able to fix it. First, I must tell you that I'm not a developer or programmer.

So, after a variable period (it could be 30 min or 4 hrs), my wifi disconnects and does not recognize my internet provider, and when it do it, I can't reconnect it because it still "freezing" and dropping. My network info is following:

```
*-network               
   descripción: Ethernet interface
   producto: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   id físico: 0
   información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
   nombre lógico: enp2s0
   versión: 07
   serie: 88:d7:f6:6f:0a:d2
   tamaño: 10Mbit/s
   capacidad: 100Mbit/s
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   recursos: irq:127 ioport:d000(size=256) memoria:ef200000-ef200fff memoria:e2100000-e2103fff
*-network
   descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
   producto: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   id físico: 0
   información del bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
   nombre lógico: wlp3s0
   versión: 00
   serie: f0:03:8c:89:a3:ed
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuración: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.10.0-42-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.57 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   recursos: irq:131 ioport:c000(size=256) memoria:ef100000-ef103fff
```

my kernel version:

```
Linux version 4.10.0-42-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-007) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) ) #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 15:57:59 UTC 2017
```

I've read [Wireless issues on 16.04 with RTL8821AE, ASUS E202S](/q/872313), but I just have an OS, not W10. Also [Wireless disconnect issues Ubuntu 16.04 with RTL8821ae](/q/797213) and other sources and I don't know what is the correct way to fix my problem, because there are different ideas about this issue, like a "bug", the Realtek or the kernel version and I'm just a newbie who is interested in learning about Linux.

I'll appreciate your help and I'm ready yo provide anything that helps me to fix my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: What exactly did you try to so far to solve the issue and what happened when you did? If we don't know that then all we can recommend is to revisit the questions that you link in your question.

Comment: Hi, I tried to install rtlwifi-new-dkms and get an error. Also, I tried to understand what to do with the Github source (https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new), but I couldn't. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Sorry, @DavidFoerster . I'll replicate the processes and I'll post them.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, I've followed the installation of rtlwifi-new-dkms and, this time, no errors have appeared. For now, my wifi is fine. I hope that this solution lasts. Is there a way that I could keep in touch with you by e-mail if some issue about this topic? I'll appreciate it a lot. I am a student eager to continue learning about Linux, and I'm newly beginning to know it (well). My email is santiago3305@hotmail.com, in case that your answer were "yes" and don't wanna post your email here. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know it. I understand it.  Sorry and I will keep my readers up to date about my situation. Thanks for your help, @DavidFoerster.